# Usage of "unless"

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, negation

> A: He just said he could help B. But right now, he doesn't seem willing
>   to help B.
>
> B: You just said you wanted to help me. Oh, ***unless*** you weren't
>   being serious, which I would get. I have been betrayed before.

What does "unless" mean in this dialogue? Doesn't it express something positive because of the double negative. Unless (if not) + weren't serious = serious

Comment: By the way, that should be 'he doesn't seem willing" not "he don't seem willing".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does "unless" mean in this dialogue?

The meaning follows the dictionary definition:

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/unless

conjunction
-  except under the circumstances that:
   "I'll be there at nine, unless the train is late."

> B: You just said you wanted to help me. Oh, unless you weren't being serious,

basically means:

> B: You just said you wanted to help me. Oh, except if you weren't being serious. (If you weren't being serious, then you don't really want to help me.)

which mean:

> B: You just said you wanted to help me. Oh, except if you were joking. (If you were joking, then you don't really want to help me.)